# Why my Gmail received an email from Yahoo?

Tags: gmail, yahoo

I recently received an email from Yahoo!, saying my Yahoo! account is an victim of the (many) hacks. However, I received this email in my Gmail account. I tried to see if my Gmail email address is registered in Yahoo! by going through 'Trouble signing in' in https://login.yahoo.com. It does't look like its registered.

Can someone please explain to me:

1. How on earth I receive the email? I never received any forwarded email from an Yahoo! account, so I am not sure if this is one.
2. How can I verify if I have a Yahoo! mail account?

Answer (score 1):

1. Perhaps someone set up your email as a recovery email for a separate yahoo account.
   Probably it was you a long time ago, as otherwise you wouldn't have clicked on the confirm email which I assume yahoo sends to the recovery email address. Although I'm not familiar with yahoo's procedures
2. I'd advise searching your gmail account for other emails from yahoo, as an account opening email may provide details of the yahoo account

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this mail is from Yahoo? Does it have the proper Yahoo ip-addresses in the headers?

It could be a forged mail, sent from elsewhere but appearing to be from Yahoo. Someone (some bot) got your gmail-address or guessed it, and using the same address for Yahoo is not a bad guess. Many people will have the same address on Outlook or Yahoo, just to prevent others from using it.

I always wonder what the purpose is of this mail. Does it have links inside, that don't point to the real Yahoo or Gmail pages?

My advice: ignore it, delete it, or report it as spam to Gmail.